# How do I do a continuous job when I press and hold until it's released then it stops?

Tags: java, android

I have a button that when clicked it will increase my mediaplayer for 10s but I want to press and hold it will increase continuously until released.

```
btn10s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition() + 10000); 
      }
    });
```

Thank !

Answer (score 1):

The method onClick works when you touch and release the button.

But when you want to do something in an event of touching the button,
you need the method called

`onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){}`